# What is the best way to clean Lovibond tintometer quartz cuvette used for oil?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I work in a laboratory where we regularly check edible oil color by using a Lovibond colorimeter. Some people suggested me to wash the quartz cuvette using soap solution.

But I am thinking about washing the quartz cuvette by using acetone solution and then leave it to dry in air. Is this method correct?

Comment: The best way is to refer to the manual, or ask a service engineer.

Comment: Any solvent that is both reasonably volatile and in which your oils are highly soluble will work. If your oils dissolve readily in acetone, go ahead and use it. But if they don't dissolve easily in it, the residue will just stay on the cuvette during the acetone wash